# Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData) in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

i calling Rest API in order to call i have some parameters as dictionary format and passing to api at some point i getting crash in conversion son type

here my sample code :

```
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration .defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)

    self.profieImage = UIImage(named: "calendar.png")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profieImage, 1)

    let params = ["fname":"Martin","lname":"Raj","gender":"Male","dob":"1997-9-14","email":"xx@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"00000","pancard":"vvvv","profileImg":imageData!] as Dictionary!

    let urlString = NSString(format:"http://my.api.call");
    print("url string is \(urlString)")
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: NSString(format: "%@", urlString)as String)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 30
    request.addValue("mobile", forHTTPHeaderField: "true")
    request.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "")
    request.HTTPBody  = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])



    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        {
            (let data: NSData?, let response: NSURLResponse?, let error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // 1: Check HTTP Response for successful GET request
            guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, receivedData = data
                else {
                    print("error: not a valid http response")
                    return
            }

            switch (httpResponse.statusCode){
            case 200:
                let response = NSString (data: receivedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                print("response==\(response)")

                default:
                break
            }    
    }
```

my log prints this statement :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

**`NSData` in JSON is not supported.**

For example you could convert the data to a Base-64 encoded string

```
let imageDataBase64 = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
let params = ["fname":"Martin","lname":"Raj","gender":"Male","dob":"1997-9-14","email":"xx@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"00000","pancard":"vvvv","profileImg":imageDataBase64]
```

On the server side you need to decode the string back to `NSData`

`params` is a non-optional dictionary (the compiler can infer that), the type casting to implicit unwrapped `Dictionary` is meaningless and not needed.

Comment: hi thank for u your answer. but now i getting this as output log error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8fbb828460 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://my.api.call, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://milestogether.in/api/v1/user, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.})

Comment: my network is working fine previous api call i getting response

Comment: In any case you can't send `NSData` in a JSON string

Comment: your answer working fine, one small issue can u reply when u c this comment ?